Output file '/app/vite.config.d.mts' has not been built from source file '/app/vite.config.mts'
I am encountering an issue with my tsconfig.json configuration while building my React + Vite project. The error message indicates that a file is matched by the include pattern, and I am unsure how to resolve it.
Here’s the relevant part of my tsconfig.json:
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ESNext",
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,
    "lib": ["DOM", "DOM.Iterable", "ESNext"],
    "allowJs": false,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": false,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "baseUrl": "src"
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "include": ["src", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "src/**/*", "vite.config.mts"],
  "references": [{ "path": "./tsconfig.node.json" }]
}

Issue:
The error message I receive is:
tsconfig.json:21:57
21   "include": ["src", "**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "src/**/*", "vite.config.mts"],
                                                           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
File is matched by include pattern specified here.

What I’ve Tried:
I have reviewed the include patterns in my tsconfig.json.
I tried removing vite.config.mts from the include array but still faced issues.
Questions:
How can I resolve this issue related to the include patterns?
Is it necessary to include vite.config.mts in the include array?

Looks like your patterns are including the same files twice,
For ex,"**/*.ts" will match src/app.ts and so will "src/**/*" match it.
So, I think you should probably just go with
"include": ["**/*.ts", "**/*.tsx", "vite.config.mts"]

or simply
"include": ["src/**/*", "vite.config.mts"]


Your Solution is not working.

@DikshitPatel what's the error

again come same error
